# DIV Alignment Doesn't Appear Correctly In Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a group of divs, that align perfectly side by side in a list in firefox, but it doesnot align correctly in chrome, as in the second list only 2 div's appear and it's kind of hard to figureout the problem.

Here is a link to the site, please note that it is **NSFW**: http://betterexcitingsexnetwork.com/

You can see that in the second row only two boxes appear instead of three, and in the last row only one row appears.

Here is the css I used :

```
.content_list {
clear: right;
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
}

media="screen"
.content_list {
position: relative;
width: 180px;
float: left;
margin: 0 25px 32px 0;
list-style: none;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Everything works perfect in Firefox but it's messed up in chrome.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that some of the `.content_list` divs are larger/higher than the others (for example when 'A Beginners Guide to Enjoyable' gets wrapped in two rows).

Make all the `.content_list` of the same height, for example

```
.content_list{
      height:270px;

      /*and perhaps to prevent content overflowing out of the div*/
      overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I didn't notice that but it really solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

interesting website you got there :)
limit the height (height: 282px;) or make it larger.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this was the right answer for my question.And btw, this is my client is site not mine. :)